# How to adjust size of matplotlib plot to fit into pyqt frame

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

I am trying to add a plot into qt window, but i can't fit that into the window it is overflowing how to properly place the plot into qt window?

i created a frame with width 650 and height 600 and i want to add plot into this frame

```
        self.XYFrame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.top)
        self.XYFrame.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(650, 600))
        self.XYFrame.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(650, 600))
        self.XYFrame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.XYFrame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.XYFrame.setObjectName("XYFrame")
        self.horizontalLayout_9 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.XYFrame)
        self.horizontalLayout_9.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_9")

        xy_plot = self.plot.plotXY()
        self.plotWidget = FigureCanvas(xy_plot)
        self.horizontalLayout_9.addWidget(self.plotWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.XYFrame)
```

Here is my plotXY()

```
        def plotXY(self):
        height, parameter = self.connection.XYPlotData()
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        ax.set(xlabel = "Relative humidity", ylabel = "Height")
        ax.plot(height, parameter)
        return fig
```

this how the plot looks now i wanted fit the plot completely into window with weigh background without overflowing
[image]

i tried `fig.tight_layout()` and `fig.subplots_adjust(0.2, 0.2, 0.8, 0.8)` in `plotXY()` but it's not working

code for testing

main.py

```
    import sys
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QMainWindow
    
    from ui import *
    # from mainWindowUI import *
    
    class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            QMainWindow.__init__(self)
            self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
            self.ui.setupUi(self)
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        mainWindow = MainWindow()
        mainWindow.setWindowState(QtCore.Qt.WindowMaximized)
        mainWindow.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

ui.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file '.\ui\mainWInLay.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.4
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
# from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [100, 125, 150, 175, 200, 225, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 650,700, 750, 775, 800, 825, 850, 875, 900, 925,950,975,1000]
y = [104.355,89.6661,86.6984,78.7212,104.783,103.04,53.765,21.0933,21.8741,24.0535,28.5814,46.6883,61.0047,79.1699,87.5734,89.2936,88.4784,86.8854,84.4816,82.6208,82.166,82.0942,83.798,82.3396,77.1371,82.0763,76.2785]

def plotXY():
    height, parameter = x, y
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set(xlabel = "Relative humidity", ylabel = "Height")
    ax.plot(height, parameter)
    return fig

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1389, 600)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("")


        # self.plot = Plot()

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(43, 54, 72);")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.mainFrame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.mainFrame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.mainFrame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.mainFrame.setObjectName("mainFrame")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.mainFrame)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.top = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.mainFrame)
        self.top.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.top.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.top.setObjectName("top")
        self.horizontalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.top)
        self.horizontalLayout_7.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_7.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_7")
        self.contourFrame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.top)
        self.contourFrame.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(650, 600))
        self.contourFrame.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(650, 600))
        self.contourFrame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.contourFrame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.contourFrame.setObjectName("contourFrame")
        self.horizontalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.contourFrame)
        self.horizontalLayout_8.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_8.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_8.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_8")

        # self.url = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(r"data.html")
        # self.webview = QWebEngineView(self.contourFrame)
        # self.webview.load(self.url)
        # # self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.contourFrame)
        # # self.widget.setStyleSheet("")
        # # self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        # self.horizontalLayout_8.addWidget(self.webview)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# HERE IS THE FRAME THAT I WANT TO INSRET MY PLOT

        self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.contourFrame)
        self.XYFrame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.top)
        self.XYFrame.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(650, 600))
        self.XYFrame.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(650, 600))
        self.XYFrame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.XYFrame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.XYFrame.setObjectName("XYFrame")
        self.horizontalLayout_9 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.XYFrame)
        self.horizontalLayout_9.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_9")

        xy_plot = plotXY()
        self.plotWidget = FigureCanvas(xy_plot)
        self.horizontalLayout_9.addWidget(self.plotWidget)


#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.XYFrame)

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.top)
        self.bottom = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.mainFrame)
        self.bottom.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 250))
        self.bottom.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 250))
        self.bottom.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.bottom.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.bottom.setObjectName("bottom")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.bottom)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(10)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.selectionFrame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.bottom)
        self.selectionFrame.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 250))
        self.selectionFrame.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 250))
        self.selectionFrame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.selectionFrame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.selectionFrame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.selectionFrame.setObjectName("selectionFrame")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.selectionFrame)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.dayMonFrame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.selectionFrame)
        self.dayMonFrame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.dayMonFrame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.dayMonFrame.setObjectName("dayMonFrame")
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.dayMonFrame)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.dayLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.dayMonFrame)
        self.dayLabel.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 25))
        self.dayLabel.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 25))
        self.dayLabel.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(86, 101, 127);\n"
"font-size:18px;")
        self.dayLabel.setObjectName("dayLabel")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.dayLabel)
        self.daySpinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.dayMonFrame)
        self.daySpinBox.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 25))
        self.daySpinBox.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 25))
        self.daySpinBox.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.daySpinBox.setObjectName("daySpinBox")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.daySpinBox)
        self.monLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.dayMonFrame)
        self.monLabel.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 25))
        self.monLabel.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 25))
        self.monLabel.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(86, 101, 127);\n"
"font-size:18px;")
        self.monLabel.setObjectName("monLabel")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.monLabel)
        self.monSpinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.dayMonFrame)
        self.monSpinBox.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 25))
        self.monSpinBox.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 25))
        self.monSpinBox.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.monSpinBox.setObjectName("monSpinBox")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.monSpinBox)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.dayMonFrame)
        self.paramprsFrame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.selectionFrame)
        self.paramprsFrame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.paramprsFrame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.paramprsFrame.setObjectName("paramprsFrame")
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.paramprsFrame)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_4")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.paramprsFrame)
        self.label.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 25))
        self.label.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 25))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(86, 101, 127);\n"
"font-size:18px;")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.label)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.paramprsFrame)
        self.comboBox.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 25))
        self.comboBox.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 25))
        self.comboBox.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.comboBox)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.paramprsFrame)
        self.label_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 25))
        self.label_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 25))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(86, 101, 127);\n"
"font-size:18px;")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.paramprsFrame)
        self.comboBox_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 25))
        self.comboBox_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 25))
        self.comboBox_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.comboBox_2)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.paramprsFrame)
        self.latLonFrame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.selectionFrame)
        self.latLonFrame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.latLonFrame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.latLonFrame.setObjectName("latLonFrame")
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.latLonFrame)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.latLonFrame)
        self.label_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 25))
        self.label_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 25))
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(86, 101, 127);\n"
"font-size:18px;")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.comboBox_3 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.latLonFrame)
        self.comboBox_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 25))
        self.comboBox_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 25))
        self.comboBox_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.comboBox_3.setObjectName("comboBox_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.comboBox_3)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.latLonFrame)
        self.label_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 25))
        self.label_4.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 25))
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(86, 101, 127);\n"
"font-size:18px;")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_4)
        self.comboBox_4 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.latLonFrame)
        self.comboBox_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 25))
        self.comboBox_4.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 25))
        self.comboBox_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.comboBox_4.setObjectName("comboBox_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.comboBox_4)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.latLonFrame)
        self.btnFrame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.selectionFrame)
        self.btnFrame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.btnFrame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.btnFrame.setObjectName("btnFrame")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.btnFrame)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 10, 125, 35))
        self.pushButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(125, 35))
        self.pushButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(125, 35))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border:1px solid black;\n"
"border-radius:15px;")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.btnFrame)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.selectionFrame)
        self.timeFrame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.bottom)
        self.timeFrame.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(825, 250))
        self.timeFrame.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(825, 250))
        self.timeFrame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.timeFrame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.timeFrame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.timeFrame.setObjectName("timeFrame")
        self.horizontalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.timeFrame)
        self.horizontalLayout_6.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_6.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_6.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_6")

        # self.timeWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.timeFrame)
        # self.timeWidget.setObjectName("timeWidget")
        # self.time_plot = self.plot.plotTime(13, 1)
        # self.timePlotWindow  = FigureCanvas(self.time_plot)
        # self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.timePlotWindow)

        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.timeFrame)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.bottom)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.mainFrame)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1389, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")

        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.dayLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Day"))
        self.monLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Month"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Parameters"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Pressure"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Latitude"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Longitude"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc, hi i added the question with the code to reproduce the proble and i commented the portion i having troble the variables are name poorly now

Comment: what is `Plot`? please read the links and review the [tour] and also read [ask]

Comment: @eyllanesc i have to draw two plots and data is retrieving from database so ```Plot``` is a class which contains the functions to set the ```XYPlot()``` and ```timePlot()``` i will comment it out it is not import to the problem i am facing now

Comment: You can comment on the import but you are still using it:  `self.plot = Plot()`. How do you think I can reproduce the problem with a code that is missing a lot?

Comment: @eyllanesc sorry, i actually copied the wrong file, it wasn't the file i made changes to post here

Comment: @eyllanesc i updated ui.py now

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "i wanted fit the plot completely into window with weigh background without overflowing"? Are you referring to the fact that the plots are not fully shown? If that's the case, it's because you are setting a lot of minimum/fixed sizes, most importantly `contourFrame`, `XYFrame`, `selectionFrame` and `timeFrame` all have minimum sizes that are *too* big. Use fixed/minimum sizes with care and only when *really* necessary (in your case, almost never, not even the other widgets) and let the layout managers to do their job.